# Error Level Analysis with PHP

Tags: php, image

I am not a coder, but I do understand logic and usually I am able to do simple coding with PHP.

I'm looking to implement **Error Level Analysis** with PHP. You can see an example in [this link.](http://fotoforensics.com)

Is it possible to implement ELA with ImageMagick or GD ? Any functions that I should look into it ?

Comment: Error level analysis of what? What are they doing to the image in your reference? What is the algorithm or mathematics of what they are doing. What is a reference? What have you tried?

Comment: The link you post, https://fotoforensics.com, is not accessible. It is an upload form.  Do you have the correct link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reference - http://www.errorlevelanalysis.com - seems to imply that you recompress a JPG image at some other compression amount (namely, 95%) and then do a pixel-by-pixel difference. You can do that in ImageMagick (or PHP Imagick).

For example in ImageMagick 6:

Input:

[image]

```
convert barn.jpg \( +clone -quality 95 \) -compose difference -composite -auto-level -gamma 1.5 barn_ela.png
```

[image]

I have stretched the result to full dynamic range using -auto-level and then did a non-linear gamma adjustment to enhance the differences.

See also https://sites.google.com/site/elsamuko/forensics/ela, where they provide two separate images and are looking for where they differ most as change detection.